# Azure Devops Git - Get version by date

Tags: c#, git, azure-devops, tfvc, tfs-sdk

Recently I moved from TFVC to Git Version control. Up until now I have been getting the file items for a specific date using TfvcVersionDescriptor date type like this:

```
var version = new TfvcVersionDescriptor { VersionType = TfvcVersionType.Date, Version = date };
```

Is there any way to achieve this using GitHttpClient? I need to generate some trend analysis and getting the list of files for a specific date is very important. If there is no functionality to retrieve by date, is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GitHttpClient.GetCommitsAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.githttpclientbase.getcommitsasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet) with a `GitQueryCommitsCriteria` object similar to

```
GitQueryCommitsCriteria searchCriteria = new GitQueryCommitsCriteria()
{
    FromDate = new DateTime(2019, 2, 2).ToString(),
    ToDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
    ItemVersion = new GitVersionDescriptor()
    {
        Version = "master",
        VersionType = GitVersionType.Branch
    }
};
var commits = await client.GetCommitsAsync(repo.Id, searchCriteria);
```

It will return a `List<GitCommitRef>` with `GitCommitRef.CommitId` (SHA-1) to identify the commit.

And then use [`GitHttpClient.GetItemsAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.githttpclientbase.getitemsasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet) or another variation with

```cs
new GitVersionDescriptor()
{
    VersionType = GitVersionType.Commit,
    Version = commitId // value from above
};
```

to get the files.

Comment: This worked for me. I got the latest commit from the list of the commitrefs. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**For TFVC:** You have `TfvcVersionDescriptor` which you have been using for long time.

**And For Git:** The corresponding class is [GitVersionDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.gitversiondescriptor?view=azure-devops-dotnet).
It only accepts three fields: `branch, commit, tag`. It doesn't support `Date` filed like what `TfvcVersionDescriptor` does, we can't control this behavior since it's by design of the SDK.

(You could add feature request about modifying the GitVersionType Enum from the SDK [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html))

Comment: I checked the documentation for GitVersionDescriptor but I could not find any version type called Date (Could only find - branch, tag, or commit ) where as TfvcVersionDescriptor had a specific version type called Date. Please correct if I am missing something. @lance-li-msft

Comment: @littlemisslilycane Sorry for my misunderstanding, I once thought you're just wanting to know something about how to move code from TFVC to GIT... If you're trying to get something like `GitVersionType.Date`, I'm afraid this is not supported. ..

Comment: Git and TFVC have different structure so their VersionType Enum have different fields. Most of the important, the GitVersionType doesn't contain the Date field by design of the SDK, you can't achieve what you want unless the team of the SDK make changes to the SDk itself.

Comment: Thanks @lance-li-msft I will create a feature request because I think it would be useful. There might be some custom devops widgets or applications which generate trend data based on the file content at a particular date.

Answer (score 1):

Which date are you interested in?

- when the original author wrote their patch `GitCommit.Author.GitUserDate.Date`
- when this commit object was created `GitCommit.Committer.GitUserDate.Date`
- when a pull request was created / pushed
- when this branch was updated

Because git is designed to be a distributed system, commit's don't have an obvious relationship to datetime values. Sometimes the real-world is messy and there isn't a simple answer.

Comment: thanks Jeremy. I thought it would be as simple as TFS version by date (having not worked in git that much) ...I will have to figure out a way to use the commit dates to get the files I need I think.